# How to represent known size set of unknown size elements with Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have 256 elements(that are lists of unknown length) and I want to represent them in Java.
In **c++** I would use something like this:

```
vector<int> aList[255];//This is C++ example
```

In Java I tried using:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] aList = new ArrayList<Integer>[256];
```

But the Java compiler forbids "Generic Array Creation"

I also tried using:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>  bList = new ArrayList<>(256);
```

But when I do

```
bList.get(67) //or any other value
```

I get an index out of bounds Exception(the bList size is 0), so my question is how to represent best such data or should I just populate bList with null values(256 null values in this example)?

**Edit**: Ok, by the answers i think i will use the solution with

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>  bList = new ArrayList<>(256);
```

And then just populate the outer array with `new ArrayLiist()`, since i need to iterate over it in order i do not know

Comment: Did you read the documentation of what `new ArrayList<>(256)` means? It's allocating an *empty* (size 0) list with *capacity* 256.

Comment: The bList approach is actually the proper one, but just remove the constructor parameter and fill them on demand when creating the sublists.

Answer (score 3):

An array list is a self-resizable array. Therefore it has two important internal values. The capacity (size of allocated internal array) and the size (the actual number of elements). From the documentation:

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

For your case this means that your are allocating an ArrayList that allows adding 255 elements without resizing. It does not mean that you are allowed to access any of those indices yet.

Therefore you have to initialize the values first like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>  bList = new ArrayList<>(256);
for(int i = 0; i< 256; i++) {
    bList.add(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

This is actually creating an array of arraylists.

Answer (score 2):

A list in Java is not the same as an Array. Think of a list as a sequence of elements (without gaps!).
`ArrayList` is just an implementation of a list. Although it uses an array to internally store its elements, it still has to behave like any other list (e.g. a `LinkedList`).

Java lists (so even if it is an `ArrayList`) keeps track of how many elements have already been added. So even when you create list like that:         `List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(256);`, it still knows that it is empty at this point, so accessing the 67th element fails.

If having a behaviour like that is not suitable for you, then you should not use a list here, you could simply use an array instead of an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are *resizable arrays*. You don't have to (but you can)declare ther initial size - they will grow as needed, just add elements to them.

Since you have been using arrays in c++, you can do the same thing in java eg

```
int[] yourArray=new int[256];
```

and access it like `yourArray[67]`

As for lists, you will have to initialize them first (aka add elements) as those keep track of what you have added to them. To do this you can eg

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    myList.add(null);
}
```

and then myList.get(67);

will return `null` but will not throw an exception.

All of those applies to 2d arrays and lists.

Comment: I think OP wants to create an array of generic arraylists for some reason.

Comment: Yes, but i want to represent sort of Array of Arrays, or just a table. Lets say its an table of size n by k. I know n and don't know k. What is the Pest representation of such data from performance/optimalization perspective?

Comment: thats just int And as I wrote, the same applies to 2d arrays (your *table*)

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an array of a generic type like that. Your best alternative is a 2D array:

```
Integer[][] aArray = new Integer[256][];
```

If you need to use a `List<Integer>[]`, then you can circumvent the limitation by creating your own non-generic sub-class:

```
class IntList extends ArrayList<Integer> {}
...
ArrayList<Integer>[] aList = new IntList[256];
```

Just note that with this option you can't add `new ArrayList<Integer>()` to `aList` (array store exception), so you'd have to create `new IntList()` objects

Answer (score 0):

Is the size really **unknown** or just **arbitrary/dynamic**?

- If it merely has an **arbitrary size** (which is known but may change
  over time), use `Set` (distinct, unordered) or `List` (ordered,
  non-distinct) or `Deque` (ordered, with double ended stack
  operations).
- If the **size is really unknown**, treat the list as
  `Iterable` (can produce a **finite** or **non-finite** `Iterator` for looping
  over the elements) or expose it as `Stream` (which again can be
  finite/non-finite).